# Data matched for delete action but 0 record affected in NodeJS and MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am using Node.js to implement the API endpoint for the delete action in a wishlist. However, I am encountering an issue where the delete query does not work as expected. Specifically, when both colorID and storageID are NULL, the delete action succeeds, and the corresponding data is removed. However, if either colorID or storageID is not NULL, the result is '0 rows affected' [referring to the output of the delete query]. This behavior is observed in my Node.js route for the delete operation.

```
router.delete("/", (req, res) => {
  const { userID, prodID, colorID, storageID } = req.body;
  const sql = `
    DELETE FROM wishlist 
    WHERE prodID = ? 
      AND userID = ? 
      AND (colorID = ? OR (colorID IS NULL AND ? IS NULL))
      AND (storageID = ? OR (storageID IS NULL AND ? IS NULL));
  `;

  db.query(
    sql,
    [prodID, userID, colorID, colorID, storageID, storageID],
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error("Error deleting from wishlist:", err);
        res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
      } else {
        console.log(`Deleted ${result.affectedRows} record(s).`);
        res.send(result);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

[My NodeJS route for delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DEYT.png)

[MySQL data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXgda.png)

[The server response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcAHN.png)

[The response if delete succeed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHKA2.png)
This is when the colorID and storageID is Null
Everythings work fine when i testng query[Testing query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEEfF.png)

Comment: Can you share the output of `console.log(req.body)` ? Also be careful with `DELETE` bodies, they are not universally supported because `DELETE` is not recommended to have a body.

Comment: This question would be a bit better if you shared the _exact_ case that is not working for you but should work (no extra irrelevant cases) and embed this information as syntax-highlighted text instead of screenshots.

Comment: Pls check if the absence of a parameyer is passed as null or as '' (empty string) or as 'null'. The latter two would explain why your query cannot match any rows.

Comment: Sure thanks @Evert
This is the body when having full data and no records deleted: 
~~~
this is the body when have full data { userID: '54', prodID: 45, storageID: 4, colorID: 2 }
Deleted 0 record(s).
DELETE /wishlist/ 200 15.743 ms - 128
~~~

And when NULL data exist, the delete action succeeded:
~~~
this is the body when have null data { userID: '54', prodID: 105, storageID: null, colorID: null }
Deleted 1 record(s).
DELETE /wishlist/ 200 3.555 ms - 128
~~~